# Difference between predicted value and expected value for binary model

Tags: least-squares, expected-value, binary-data, logit, probit

For a binary model with Y as the dependent variable and X1, X2, and X3 as independent variable, my understanding is that the predicted value is the value of Y at specified values of of X1,X2,X3. Ex. if LPM is Y = β1∗X1+β2∗X2+β3∗X3+ϵ. The predicted value (Y) for X1 = X2 = X3 + 1 is β1+β2+β3.

For expected value, is it the average of the predicted value at specified values for all the observations in the sample? I am kind of confused about the difference between the two. Can someone explain the difference?

Comment: Could you explain if X1 = X2 = X3 + 1 and then Y = β1 + β2 + β3?

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between the predicted value and the expected value. Predicted values tend to be for specific points of interest. Expected value is a concept that applies to the entire distribution/dataset. Read on for more details.

Let's assume a simpler model: $Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1X + \epsilon$. For a linear regression, we say that $\epsilon \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$. The key thing to note here is that $\epsilon$ is a Normal random variable, which then makes $Y$ a Normal random variable with mean $\beta_0 + \beta_1X$ and variance $\sigma^2$.

So we have that the expected value of $E[Y] = \beta_0 + \beta_1X$. This is only true because of the model assumption we made earlier (i.e. $\epsilon$ is Normal with 0 mean).

Note that we could have assumed that $\epsilon$ was not Normally distributed, or that it had a non-zero mean. In this case, the expected value of $Y$ would not be something other than $\beta_0 + \beta_1X$

Now, the predicted value of $Y$ at a given point, $X_i$, is $\beta_0 + \beta_1X_i$. If $X_i = 2$ then $Y(2) = \beta_0 + 2 \times \beta_1$

Comment: Would you explain, the expected value of $Y$ would not be something other than $\beta_0 + \beta_1X$? Do you mean $\epsilon$ won't be shown in expected value of Y?

Comment: The expected value of $\epsilon$ is 0, since were assuming its normal with mean 0.

Comment: Isn't that violate the assumption, Note that we could have assumed that ϵ was not Normally distributed, or that it had a non-zero mean?

Comment: But we do assume that it’s Normally distributed with zero mean. Given that assumption, the expected value of epsilon is 0.